# Run-time error 381: Could not set the error property. Invalid property array index (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't used VBA before I just used it recently to create an Automated Entry Form in excel for a current project in my work following a tutorial on Youtube. However, when I reached this step I get an error (Run-time error 381: Could not set the error property. Invalid property array index) whenever I launch the application which appears to be due the number of columns in my worksheet (16) and it is supposed to be less than 10 to work with the list function (if I'm not mistaken).

While searching for a solution on internet I found a suggestion of using another method (arrays) rather than using lists. However, I couldn't understand how it works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Reset()

    Dim iRow As Long
    
    iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] ' identifying the last row
    
    With frmForm
        
        .LetterNo.Value = ""
        .LetterDate.Value = ""
        .LetterAmount.Value = ""
        
        .NameBenf.Value = ""
        .AddressBenf.Value = ""
        .Reference.Value = ""
        
        .AcctBenf.Value = ""
        .BankBenf.Value = ""
        .BenfBankAdd.Value = ""
        .SwiftBenf.Value = ""
        .IBANBenf.Value = ""
        .SwiftNotif.Value = False
        
        
        
        .LetterCurrency.Clear
        
        .LetterCurrency.AddItem "EURO"
        .LetterCurrency.AddItem "USD"

        
    
        .AccountHold.Clear
        
        .AccountHold.AddItem "ZZZZZZZ"
        .AccountHold.AddItem "CCCCCCC"
        
        
        
        
        .AcctNo.Clear
        
        .AcctNo.AddItem "0000 0000 1111 1111"
        .AcctNo.AddItem "1111 1111 0000 0000"

          
          
         
        .OurBankCode.Clear
        
        
        .OurBankCode.AddItem "44444444"
        .OurBankCode.AddItem "3333333"
        .OurBankCode.AddItem "22222222"
        .OurBankCode.AddItem "11111111"
        
        
        .lstDatabase.Column = 16
        .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
        
        
        If iRow > 1 Then
            
            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:I" & iRow
        Else
            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database !A2:I2"
            
        End If
        
    End With

End Sub


Sub Submit()

    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    
    iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A] + 1
    
    With sh
    
        .Cells(iRow, 1) = frmForm.LetterNo.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 2) = [Text(Now(), "DD/MM/YYY")]
        .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.LetterCurrency.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 4) = frmForm.LetterAmount.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 5) = frmForm.AccountHold.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 6) = frmForm.AcctNo.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 7) = frmForm.OurBankCode.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 8) = frmForm.NameBenf.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 9) = frmForm.AddressBenf.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 10) = frmForm.AcctBenf.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 11) = frmForm.BankBenf.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 12) = frmForm.BenfBankAdd.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 13) = frmForm.SwiftBenf.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 14) = frmForm.IBANBenf.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 15) = frmForm.Reference.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 16) = IIf(frmForm.SwiftNotif.Value = True, "YES", "")
    
    End With

End Sub


Sub Show_Form()

    frmForm.Show
    
End Sub
```

Comment: From what line does it show the "Run-time error 381"?

Comment: .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database !A2:I2" - there seems to be an unnecessary space after Database

Comment: iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A] + 1 - a parenthesis is missing here

Comment: @WilsMils Apparently, It shows from the last sub (Show_Form() frmForm.Show )

Comment: You should have a Form named frmForm that has objects in it. Learn how to understand TextBox, ListBox, ComboBox & CommandButton get populated and trigger. That way you may modify the codes that you see in the Internet.